"Best" way to inject a Livewire component into the response with Laravel middleware
I want to add a Livewire component to every request using middleware rather than having to manually add the component. I've done a bit of research and have looked at Spatie's Laravel cookie consent package, which accomplishes something very similar. To determine that they add their component to the right request (like not JSON, file download, XML, or other requests), they look for a closing </body> tag. Would it be just as "good" (accurate, in line with best practices, etc.) to instead check the response header Content-Type for text/html + that it isn't a redirect using the isRedirection() method? For example, rather than Spatie's containsBodyTag() function, this:
protected function isHtml(Response $response): bool
{
    return str_contains($response->headers->get('Content-Type'), 'text/html') && ! $response->isRedirection();
}


Maybe. Some apps might send partial HTML responses that aren't intended to be a full HTML page (like a replacement set of HTML for a particular div); depending on your component, this might not be ideal.

OK @ceejayoz , this clarifies things for me. Thank you. I really just wanted to know why Spatie's approach was better, and you've answered that for me. Now that I think of it, there are all kinds of HTML responses that aren't complete HTML documents with a </body> tag. If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Both approaches may have trade-offs depending on your app's particular details.
Spatie's approach of checking for a body tag will avoid messing with HTML partials your app might return; HTML intended to be swapped-out for a particular div in your existing page, for example. Many apps don't do this at all, so the answer is to some extent "it depends".
